# Angular Smart Table with Ajax Data won't output

Tags: angularjs, datagrid, smart-table

I try to use [smart Tabl](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/)e on remote Data but I do not get any output. I've been reading in documentation that on ajax data should be used the stSafeSrc attribute, but obviously I'm doing something wrong.

**My Markup looks as it follows**

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="container">

{% verbatim %}
{{ rowCollection }}

<button type="button" ng-click="addRandomItem(row)" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add Feed
</button>

<table st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="rowCollection" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Feed Name</th>
        <th>parsed Items</th>
        <th>Feed Link</th>
        <th>Feed Type</th>
        <th>Import</th>
        <th>Categorize</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <tr ng-repeat="row in displayedCollection">
        <td>{{row.feed_type}}</td>
        <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
{% endverbatim %}
</div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
october.controllers['dashboard/feeds'] = function ($scope, $filter , $request) {
    $.request('onFeeds', {success: function(data, scope){
        this.success(data).done(function() {
            $scope.rowCollection = [];
            $scope.rowCollection = angular.fromJson(data.result);
            $scope.displayedCollection = [].concat($scope.rowCollection);
            console.log($scope.rowCollection); // Array of Objects is present
        });
    }
});

}
```

Comment: What's `$request`? I ask as i notice you don't use it, but have `$.request` instead.

Comment: $request is a part of a framework(october cms) with you can make ajax calls

Comment: So the code for your controller should be `$request('onFeeds',` not `$.request('onFeeds',` then?

Comment: `console.log($scope.rowCollection); // Array of Objects is present¸`

Comment: Not sure i understand? Are you saying that `$.request` works?

Comment: yes more than that if I click the button `add Feeds` the data is going to be shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the look of it you're using this

https://github.com/responsiv/angular-plugin

You're controller code is wrong. You're calling `$.request()` instead of `$request()`, which is something their `$request` service actually proxies http requests to. This is why it appears to be working. But you're not actually making a http request through their service - which would be inside angular - you're making it outside of angular, through a third party library they use.

You need to change your controller to the following:

```
october.controllers['dashboard/feeds'] = function ($scope, $filter , $request) {
    $request('onFeeds', {success: function(data, scope){
        this.success(data).done(function() {
            $scope.rowCollection = [];
            $scope.rowCollection = angular.fromJson(data.result);
            $scope.displayedCollection = [].concat($scope.rowCollection);
            console.log($scope.rowCollection); // Array of Objects is present
        });
    }
});

}
```

Then their `$request` service will call `$rootScope.$apply()` - see line 110 of,

https://github.com/responsiv/angular-plugin/blob/master/assets/js/angular-bridge.js